# Android: EditText bug

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my android `Activity`, I need to add two `EditText`s, one for title and the other for description.

When I am editing the first `EditText`(Title) it's fine but when i am trying to edit the second `EditText`(Description) it writes strange characters and when I touch wherever in my activity that causes an exception.

I tried to create a new `Activity` and add the `EditText`, but i still have the same problem.

**Stack trace:**

```
E/InputEventReceiver(10790): Exception dispatching input event.
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at android.graphics.Paint.getTextRunAdvances(Paint.java:2256)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at android.text.TextLine.handleText(TextLine.java:815)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at android.text.TextLine.handleRun(TextLine.java:970)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at android.text.TextLine.measureRun(TextLine.java:483)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at android.text.TextLine.measure(TextLine.java:362)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at android.text.Layout.getHorizontal(Layout.java:856)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at android.text.Layout.getHorizontal(Layout.java:834)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at android.text.Layout.getPrimaryHorizontal(Layout.java:809)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at android.text.Layout.getPrimaryHorizontal(Layout.java:799)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at android.widget.TextView.getFocusedRect(TextView.java:6468)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at android.view.FocusFinder.findNextFocusInAbsoluteDirection(FocusFinder.java:245)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at android.view.FocusFinder.findNextFocus(FocusFinder.java:166)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at android.view.FocusFinder.findNextFocus(FocusFinder.java:97)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at android.view.FocusFinder.findNextFocus(FocusFinder.java:68)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:726)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:728)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:728)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:728)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:728)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:728)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:728)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:728)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at android.view.View.focusSearch(View.java:7738)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at android.widget.TextView.onCreateInputConnection(TextView.java:7092)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.startInputInner(InputMethodManager.java:1346)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.checkFocus(InputMethodManager.java:1518)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.viewClicked(InputMethodManager.java:1694)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at android.widget.TextView.viewClicked(TextView.java:11081)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:9588)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8981)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2425)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2425)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2425)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at android.widget.ScrollView.dispatchTouchEvent(ScrollView.java:615)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2425)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2425)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2425)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2425)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2425)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2568)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1776)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2866)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2529)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9186)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4706)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4544)
E/MessageQueue-JNI(10790):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.
E/AndroidRuntime(10790): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(10790): Process: com.bitdyne.jamaati.ui.activities, PID: 10790
E/AndroidRuntime(10790): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at android.graphics.Paint.getTextRunAdvances(Paint.java:2256)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at android.text.TextLine.handleText(TextLine.java:815)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at android.text.TextLine.handleRun(TextLine.java:970)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at android.text.TextLine.measureRun(TextLine.java:483)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at android.text.TextLine.measure(TextLine.java:362)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at android.text.Layout.getHorizontal(Layout.java:856)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at android.text.Layout.getHorizontal(Layout.java:834)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at android.text.Layout.getPrimaryHorizontal(Layout.java:809)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at android.text.Layout.getPrimaryHorizontal(Layout.java:799)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at android.widget.TextView.getFocusedRect(TextView.java:6468)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at android.view.FocusFinder.findNextFocusInAbsoluteDirection(FocusFinder.java:245)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at android.view.FocusFinder.findNextFocus(FocusFinder.java:166)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at android.view.FocusFinder.findNextFocus(FocusFinder.java:97)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at android.view.FocusFinder.findNextFocus(FocusFinder.java:68)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:726)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:728)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:728)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:728)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:728)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:728)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:728)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:728)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at android.view.View.focusSearch(View.java:7738)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at android.widget.TextView.onCreateInputConnection(TextView.java:7092)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.startInputInner(InputMethodManager.java:1346)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.checkFocus(InputMethodManager.java:1518)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.viewClicked(InputMethodManager.java:1694)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at android.widget.TextView.viewClicked(TextView.java:11081)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:9588)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8981)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2425)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2425)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2425)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at android.widget.ScrollView.dispatchTouchEvent(ScrollView.java:615)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2425)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2425)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2425)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2425)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2425)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2568)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1776)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2866)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2529)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9186)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4706)
E/AndroidRuntime(10790):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImp
```

**xml file:**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
            layout="@layout/tool_bar" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/claim_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/textbox"
                android:hint="@string/claim_title"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:textColor="@color/Gray"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/claim_desc"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/commentbox"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:hint="@string/claim_desc"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:textColor="@color/Gray"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Activity code:**

```
public class NewClaimActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
            RestClientCallback, OnClickListener {
    private EditText claimTitle;
    private EditText claimDesc;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_claim);

    claimTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.claim_title);
    claimDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.claim_desc);
    }

    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
    String title = claimTitle.getText().toString();
    String desc = claimDesc.getText().toString();
    }
    }
```

Bellow the screenshot for the edit text:

[image]

Thank you for help.

Comment: Provide some code (XMLs and how and what you do with EditTexts in java code).

Comment: can you add code and layout ? How are you grabbing the textView ?

Comment: Can you check my edited post please

Comment: How are you receiving the data ? I looks like that is the problem then.
RestClientCallback

Comment: Don't worry about this, this callback is used after the click on validate button.

Comment: Is that onClick implementation intended for the button? Because if it is, the error might be there. It gets triggered as soon as you click anywhere in the activity...

Comment: Is that the full code of `onClick()` method?

Comment: No, but please don't worry about onClick() method, because I don't rich it, and i get the exception

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34872) in the Android source code, and [here's a workaround](https://gist.github.com/pyricau/3424004) for it (you have to subclass TextView)

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing a similar problem. Though couldn't understand why is it happening but I was able to solve it by removing just a single line from the layout file.

In your xml file, remove the following:

**android:inputType="textCapSentences"**